# Userscript works in Tampermonkey on Chrome and Firefox, but doesn't work in Greasemonkey on Firefox

Tags: greasemonkey, userscripts, tampermonkey

This script works just fine in Tampermonkey on both Chrome and Firefox, but doesn't work in Greasemonkey on Firefox. When I say it doesn't work I mean the button does not show up on the page. I'm using Chrome 61.0.3163.79 and Firefox 52.3.0.

The firefox console shows this warning but I'm not sure if it's relevant:

```
unreachable code after return statement[Learn More]  jquery-1.3.2.min.js
```

Here's the code. Using greasemonkey on Firefox, I see "create button" in the console, but not "button has been created", which makes me think something is going wrong with the button creation. Any help greatly appreciated!

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name            MyScript
// @namespace       MyNS
// @description     Adds a button to insert text into 2 text boxes
// @version         0.1
// @include         *Removed for confidentiality*
// @compatible      Greasemonkey
// ==/UserScript==

var descriptionText = "myDescription";

var testingText = "myTesting";

// Check if jQuery's loaded
function GM_wait() {
    if (typeof unsafeWindow.jQuery == 'undefined') { window.setTimeout(GM_wait,100); }
    else { $ = unsafeWindow.jQuery; init(); }
}

// All your GM code must be inside this function
function init() {
    var description = $('#description');
    var testingDone = $('#testing_done');
    function insertText(template, editor) {
        if (template) {
            if (!editor._editing) {
                editor.startEdit();
            }
            editor._field.queue(function() {
                var oldVal = editor._field.val();
                editor._field.val(template + (oldVal ? "\n" : "") + oldVal);
                editor._field.keyup();
                editor._field.dequeue();
            });
        }
    }

    function createButton(editor) {
            console.log("create button:");

        editor._insertTextButton = $('<input/>')
            .attr('type', 'button')
            .attr('value', 'Insert CR Template')
            .css('margin-left', '1em')
            .click(function() {
                 insertText(testingText, testingDoneEditor);
                 insertText(descriptionText, descriptionEditor);
            });
        console.log("button has been created");
        editor._insertTextButton.insertAfter(editor._editIcon);
    }

    descriptionEditor = description.data('inlineEditor');
    testingDoneEditor = testingDone.data('inlineEditor');
    createButton(descriptionEditor);
}

GM_wait();
```

Comment: You can add `debugger` statement and debug the script line-by-line.

Comment: In firefox that is not working.

Comment: I set up browser toolbox but I'm unable to find my script in the sources. Searching all the sources for variable names from the script returns no results.

Comment: I have several `debugger` statements in my script and the toolbox is running. I see my script's log statements in the console, so I know it's being executed, but the toolbox does not pause at the `debugger` lines.

Comment: chrome.enabled and remote-enabled are already set to true. I changed prompt-connection to false but that didn't help.